# How to convert counts to percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I'm trying to make a ggplot, that shows the percentages of how often people attends religious services.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(D, aes(x = pew_churatd)) + geom_bar() + 
 scale_x_discrete (guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
 labs(x = "How often do you attend religious services?", y = "")
```

[image: This is my graph]

## Data

[image: Data]

Comment: can you share any sample data so we can assist?

Comment: Try `geom_bar(aes(y = ..count.. / sum(..count..)))` (with `..count..` you can access the value of the counts computed by geom_bar). For nice labels use `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())`.

Comment: @DeathMetal - I'm (obviously) new in R, so I'm not really sure what you mean. I added a picture in my question now from the data-guide, I don't know, if that's what you're looking for? Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @stefan - Thank you, I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

One way to produce the desired chart is to calculate percentages in the data frame, and use the percentage value as the y axis in `ggplot()`.

```
textFile <- "count,answer,text
5401,1,More than once a week
11521,2,Once a week
5332,3,Once or twice a month
9338,4,A few times a year
14708,5,Seldom
17860,6,Never
707,7,Don't know
33,8,Skipped
0,9,Not asked"

df <- read.csv(text=textFile,header = TRUE)
df$response <- factor(df$answer,labels = df$text)
df$pct <- df$count / sum(df$count) * 100

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=response,y=pct)) + geom_bar(stat="summary",fun=sum) + 
     scale_x_discrete (guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
     labs(x = "How often do you attend religious services?", y = "Percentage")
```

...and the output:

[image]

If we calculate proportions instead of percentages, we can use `scale_y_continuous()` per the comments to generate percent signs in the y axis labels.

```
df <- read.csv(text=textFile,header = TRUE)
df$response <- factor(df$answer,labels = df$text)
df$proportion <- df$count / sum(df$count)

ggplot(df,aes(x=response,y=proportion)) + geom_bar(stat="summary",fun=sum) + 
     scale_x_discrete (guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
     labs(x = "How often do you attend religious services?", y = "")
```

...and the revised output:

[image]